# Alignment of labels in itemize with text of document

Tags: itemize

I am trying to align the label in an itemize environment with the left edge of the text but am having no luck. Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}   

\begin{document}    
\newcommand{\subject}{Line 1\\Line2}

\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]  % Did not work for me
    \item[\textbf{Subject:}]\subject
\end{itemize}

blah blah blah


\end{document}
```

Basically I'd like to have "Subject" line up with the first blah.

Also I'd like Line 1 to line up with Line 2.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Load `enumitem` and set as an optional argument to `ìtemize`: `[wide=0pt]`.

Comment: changed question to include @Bernard enumitem suggestion - which did not work for me. Also added another requirement that I failed to state the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `wide=\parindent` option to the `itemize` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\newlength{\lmar} 
\settowidth{\lmar}{\textbf{Subject:}}

\begin{document}    
\newcommand{\subject}{Line 1\\Line 2 \\ Line 3}

\begin{itemize}[wide=\parindent,leftmargin=\dimexpr\lmar+\parindent+\labelsep]  % Did not work for me
    \item[\textbf{Subject:}] \subject
\end{itemize}

blah blah blah ... In order to get the most complete view of the different methods, their computation times are printed in the table below ... 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me align "Line 1" and "Line2"? (so that the "L"'s line up)

Comment: @user42927 - Sure, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks - works perfect though I am curious why the \relax wasn't needed after \parindent

Comment: actually I needed to make one small change which was to add "+\labelsep" after \parindent